# How to log Gson parsing Field by Field to find out on which field error is triggered

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Is there any way to Log Gson parsing filed by Field? Log should print name of filed and corresponding value received in response.
Example: Model class looks something like this

```
public class Item{

@SerializedName("ItemCode")
@Expose
private String ItemCode;
@SerializedName("ItemSN")
@Expose
private String ItemSN;
@SerializedName("ItemDesc")
@Expose
private String ItemDesc;

--getter setter methods--
}
```

And if response looks as follows:

```
{
"ItemCode":"A12"
"ItemSN":"123455672"
"ItemDesc":"Google Pixel"
}
```

At the time of `Gson` parsing following log should be generated

ItemCode is A12

ItemSN is 123455672

ItemDesc is Google Pixel

I want this to solve following problem. If any other solution works for this kind of problem please suggest.

One API (say init API) for my application returns JSON response which I am parsing using Retrofit-Gson-RxJava, We have two environment setup Test and Prod for prod environment response is getting parsed successfully but for test environment I am getting `NumberFormatException` which obviously tell us some `Numeric` filed is having non `Numeric` value in response.

As the size of response is huge with so many objects nested inside one another hence its getting difficult to find out exact field for which parsing is getting failed.

Comment: Doesn't look like a Gson error. Does your test API returns `"Item": 1234` instead of `"Item": "1234"` by any chance? Check what is returned by the server and check the log for the error. It probably gives you the line where the error occurs (you can post it here too, can help)

Comment: As mentioned in question I know there is some problem in response but its difficult to to find out exact location/filed as the response contains so many nested objects... trust me its really very huge and cant share here as it contains confidential info.

Comment: Can you share the error log please?

Comment: @DCoder what did you use to fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Add HttpLoggingInterceptor: compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1"

```
 public static Retrofit getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();          
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();           
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!
        instance = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't log conversions